How do I get the fine amount in this table which determined by 2 factors with reference?
I'm trying to get the value for the fine amount in this table on the left in which determined by 2 factors: no. of days & no. of offences with reference of the fine amount at the side. However I can't really get the value no matter how I trial and error with possible functions and ended up with errors which I open up and see which part of the error is in and it happens on the part where comparing the no. of days with the reference (which I putting the value from the table to be greater than or equals to the first number in the reference).
table & ref
As the reference at the side in which the no. of days is shown in strings, I got the min number of days out so as I can easily compare with the value in the table. I've tried using INDEX MATCH, Filter, Vlookup to get the fine amount but failed at the it and got to a point that I'm kind of overwhelmed because the logics seems correct but it just doesn't give me the results. The last I tried was: =FILTER(M2:N6,ISNUMBER(MATCH(G2,G2>=K2:K6,0))*ISNUMBER(MATCH(H2,M1:N1,-1)))
Appreciate if anyone could correct/help me out with this.

How did this get out of staging ground?

Try using one of the following formulas:


=LOOKUP([@[NO. OF DAYS]],--TEXTBEFORE(L$2:L$6," "),IF(H2=0,M$2:M$6,N$2:N$6))


Or, Using XLOOKUP()
=XLOOKUP([@[NO. OF DAYS]],--TEXTBEFORE(L$2:L$6," "),IF(H2=0,M$2:M$6,N$2:N$6),,-1)


Or, Using INDEX()+MATCH()
=INDEX(IF(H2=0,M$2:M$6,N$2:N$6),
 MATCH([@[NO. OF DAYS]],--TEXTBEFORE(L$2:L$6," "),1))


Using TEXTSPLIT() within LOOKUP() seems to bit shorter:
=LOOKUP([@[NO. OF DAYS]],--TEXTSPLIT(L$2:L$6," "),IF(H2,N$2:N$6,M$2:M$6))



The question lacks the expected output, but looking at the image I think you want to lookup the number of days from column G into the values of column K and match the row equal to or smaller than the lookup value.
The result should be the calculated row in column M or N, depending on the number of incidents in column L; 0 means column M, 1 or more means column N.
In that case you could use:
=INDEX(M2:N6,XMATCH(G2:G6,K2:K6,-1),1+SIGN(H2:H6))
PS it looks as if K2:K6vare not number values, but strings (left aligned). Make sure they're actual numbers or use =INDEX(M2:N6,XMATCH(G2:G6,--K2:K6,-1),1+SIGN(H2:H6))

Look up bracket for the number of days by extracting the first number, which is left to 'TO' --LEFT(INDEX(lookup_table, , 1), SEARCH("TO", INDEX(lookup_table, , 1)) - 1):
=LET(
    lookup_brackets, L2:N6,
    lookup_table, HSTACK(
        --LEFT(
            INDEX(lookup_brackets, , 1),
            SEARCH("TO", INDEX(lookup_brackets, , 1)) - 1
        ),
        DROP(lookup_brackets, , 1)
    ),
    MAP(
        G2:G6,
        H2:H6,
        LAMBDA(no_of_days, no_of_offences,
            VLOOKUP(no_of_days, lookup_table, IF(no_of_offences, 3, 2))
        )
    )
)


